# Singularity error. What is actually causing the problem here?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

I am solving the equation of motion for a nonlinear oscillator.  At values of $\nu$ greater than $\approx 0.408$, this list stop plotting, giving an error like this (for `ν = 0.4085`:

> NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 11.448194278316508`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

I'm no expert on chaos, so I'm not sure if a "singularity" is actually occurring, or what that actually entails.  I tried looking at examples of how to plot bifurcation diagrams, but those also seem to blow up, so I'm thinking that this isn't exactly related to chaos?  Is this just a result of the system instability?  Are there simply no solutions for values of $\nu$ greater than $\approx 0.408$?

```
 data = Block[{ν = 0.408, knl = 1, k = 1, m = 1, v0 = Sqrt[2]}, 
    Reap[NDSolve[{m x''[t] + k x[t] - ν knl x[t]^2 == 0, 
       x[0] == 0, x'[0] == v0, 
       WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 π] == 0, Sow[{x[t], x'[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 
       0, 1000}, MaxSteps -> ∞, 
      WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]]][[-1, 1]];

ListPlot[data]
```

Comment: Please include the error message in your question.  This will help other people google for it.

Comment: @Szabolcs  The error message was of the sort `NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 24.535410457452116`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.`  In fact, neither was true.  Instead, the solution grew faster than exponentially, as it should.

Comment: I apologize!  I'm new to the website.  That is indeed the error message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Description of the issues

It is a bit unusual to discuss an ODE system as a function of a parameter `ν` but with a fixed initial condition `x[0] == 0, x'[0] == v0`, but as such, `ν = 1/Sqrt[6]`, or approx. `0.408248`, is a sort of critical value.  The phase portraits of the ODEs for `ν > 0` all have the same look and features:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are two equilibria, a center at `{0, 0}` and an unstable saddle at `{1/ν, 0}`.  As `ν` changes, the gray separatrix moves.  It passes through the initial condition when `ν = 1/Sqrt[6]`, and the nature of the solution changes.  When `ν < 1/Sqrt[6]` (and greater than `-1/Sqrt[6]`), the solution is periodic.  When `ν > 1/Sqrt[6]`, the solution `x[t]` goes off to infinity.  At the critical value `ν == 1/Sqrt[6]`, the solution `x[t]` approaches `Sqrt[6]` as `t` goes to infinity.

The following, for the indicated value of the parameter `ν`, shows the solution with the OP's fixed initial condition in blue and the corresponding phase portrait.  The initial condition itself is indicated by a green point near the top of the y axis.  The gray curve is the separatrix for the critical value `ν == 1/Sqrt[6]`, which the blue solution curve approaches when `ν` approaches this value.  The blue changes from a loop to an open-ended curve when the red separatrix for the varying `ν` passes though the green point. (Code at end.)

[image]

Intuitively, one can conclude there is probably such bifurcation point, since there is only a restorative force if `k x[t] - ν knl x[t]^2` in the ODE is positive.  If `ν` is allowed to grow as large as we please, this cannot always be positive, and beyond some point, the repulsive force will likely be great enough to repel the mass, even if it is moving toward the center.

### Update:  Solving the system

The phase portrait above can be solved symbolically via the standard reduction of order method for autonomous equations, but we can also get a closed-form solution by transforming the ODE to a Weierstrass differential equation and solving in terms of `WeierstrassP[]`.  (For some reason, `DSolve[]` *can* solve such equations, but it could not be coaxed to go down that path with the OP's ODE.)

#### Reduction of order

Since nu and vee look the same on my web browser, I'm going to use `u`  for the "velocity", `x'[t]`, in TeX,
$$u = u(x) = dx/dt = \dot x \,.$$
The we have
$$\ddot x = {d^2x \over dt^2} = {dx \over dt}\,{du \over dx} = u\,u'\,.$$
The OP's ODE becomes $u \, u' = \nu x^2 - x$, after setting the other parameters to $1$ just as in the question.  This is separable and `DSolve` will solve it, and then we can integrate it again to get `x[t]` back...except that `DSolve` returns an implicit solution.  However, if we solve for `t` as a function of `x`, using

$${dt \over dx} = {1 \over \dot x} = {1 \over dx/dt}$$

we get an explicit parametrization. It is only a slight inconvenience to plot `{t[x], x}` instead of `{t, x[t]}`.

```
(* defines the ODE ode[ν] and it phase plane vector field vf[ν] *)
ClearAll[ode, vf];
Block[{ knl = 1, k = 1, m = 1}, 
 ode[ν_] = m u[x] u'[x] + k x - ν knl x^2 == 0;
 vf[ν_] = u {1, u'[x]} /. First@Solve[ode[ν], u'[x]] /. u[x] -> u
 ]

{dsol1} = DSolve[{ode[ν], u[0] == Sqrt[2]}, u, x]
(*  {{u -> Function[{x}, Sqrt[6 - 3 x^2 + 2 x^3 ν]/Sqrt[3]]}}  *)

{dsol} = DSolve[{t'[x] == (1/u[x] /. dsol1), t[0] == 0}, t, x]
(* long solution... *)
```

We can get the equilibria, where the velocity `u` as well as its derivative are zero, and the critical value for `ν` as follows:

```
equil = Solve[{ode[ν] /. u'[x] -> 0 /. u[x] -> u, u == 0}, {x, u}]
(*  {{x -> 0, u -> 0}, {x -> 1/ν, u -> 0}}  *)
```

Looking at the Jacobian, we can see at a glance that the origin is weakly stable and the other point is a saddle:

```
D[{ode[ν] /. u'[x] -> 0 /. u[x] -> u /. Equal -> Subtract, u}, {{x, u}}] /. equil;
MatrixForm /@ %
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I used `Discriminant[6 - 3 x^2 + 2 x^3 ν, x]` to figure out that `ν == 1/Sqrt[6]` was the critical point, but you could use

```
Solve[u[x] == 0 /. dsol1, x, Reals]
(* ConditionalExpressions with ±1/Sqrt[6] as branch points *)
```

#### Explicit solution

First we transform the ODE
$$\ddot x = \nu\, x^2 - x = \nu \left(x -{1\over2\nu}\right)^2 - {1 \over 4 \nu}$$
into the differential equation for the  Weierstrass $\wp$ function
$$\left[{\wp}'(t)\right]^2 = 4 \left[{\wp}(t)\right]^3 - g_2 {\wp}(t) - g_3\,.$$
The substitution $6y =\nu\left[x-1/(2\nu)\right]$ entails
$$6y =\nu\left(x-{1\over2\nu}\right)\ \text{or}\ x = {6 \over\nu}\,y + {1 \over 2\nu}, \quad
 6\, \dot y = \nu\, \dot x, \quad
 6\, \ddot y = \nu\, \ddot x\,.$$
It transforms the ODE to
$$\ddot y = 6\,y^2 - {1 \over 24}\,.$$
If we multiply through by $2\,\dot y$, we can integrate with respect to $t$ to get the Weierstrass equation
$${\dot y}^2 = 4y^3 - {1\over12}\,y - g_3\,,$$
where $g_3$ is a constant to be determined from the initial condition.
The general solution to this equation is
$$y = \wp(t+t_0) = \wp(t+t_0; \{1/12, g_3\})$$
where $t_0$ is a constant; in *Mathematica*, it is given by the code `WeierstrassP[t + t0, {1/12, g3}]`.
If the initial condition for $y$ is $\dot y(0) = \dot y_0$, $y(0) = y_0$,
then $g_3$ and $t_0$ are determined from
$$\dot y_0^2 = 4 y_0 - {y_0 \over 12} - g3, \quad
 y_0 = \wp(t_0, \{1/12, g_3\})$$
The second equation is very conveniently solved in *Mathematica* by

```
t0 = InverseWeierstrassP[y0, {1/12, g3}]
```

If the initial conditions on `x` are `x[0] == x0` and `x'[0] == v0`, then the solution `x[t]` is given by

```
With[{y0 = ν x0/6 - 1/12, yp0 = ν v0/6},               (* convert x-ICs to y-ICs *)
 With[{g3 = 4 y0^3 - 1/12 y0 - yp0^2},                 (* solve for g3 *)
  With[{t0 = InverseWeierstrassP[y0, {1/12 , g3}]},    (* solve for t0 *)
   With[{y = WeierstrassP[t + t0, {1/12 , g3}]},       (* solve for y *)
    x -> Function[{t}, 6/ν y + 1/(2 ν)]                (* convert y to x *)
 ]]]]
```

Here's how it looks:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Code dumps

**Animation**

The animation was really a `Manipulate[]`.

```
(* Separatrix for general ν *)
Block[{knl = 1, k = 1, m = 1, v0 = Sqrt[2 1/(6 ν^2)]},
 Assuming[ν > 0,
  {sepsol} = DSolve[{ode[ν], u[0] == v0}, u, x]
  ]]

(* Separatrix for critical value for IC  v0 == Sqrt[2]  *)
Block[{ν = 1/Sqrt[6]},
  sing = Plot[{1, -1} u[x] /. dsol1, {x, -1.5, 3.5}, PlotStyle -> Gray]
  ];

With[{knl = 1, k = 1, m = 1, v0 = Sqrt[2]},
 Manipulate[
  Block[{ν = 1/Sqrt[6] + dν^3},
   Show[
    sing,
    StreamPlot[{u, -((k x - ν knl x^2)/m)},
     {x, -1.45, 3.55}, {u, -1.55, 1.55},
     StreamStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.5]}],
    Quiet@Plot[
      {1, -1} u[x] /. sepsol, {x, -1.5, 3.5}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.5]}],
    Plot[
     {1, -1} u[x] /. dsol1, {x, -1.5, 3.5}],
    Graphics[
     {Red, PointSize[Medium], 
      foo = Point[{x, u} /. 
         NSolve[{u, -((k x - ν knl x^2)/m)} == {0, 0}]]}],
    PlotLabel -> Row[{HoldForm@ν, " = ", Chop@ν}]
    ]],
  {dν, -(1/6^(1/6)), 0.2^(1/3)}, TrackedSymbols :> {dν}]
 ]
```

To make a movie out of it, I (1) changed `Manipulate[..]` to `movie = Table[..]`, (2) deleted the `TrackedSymbols..` option, and (3) changed the iterator to `{d\[Nu], -(1/6^(1/6)), 0.2^(1/3), 0.05}`.
Then you can make a movie with `Export["file.gif", movie]`.

**`Manipulate[]` for the `WeierstrassP[]` solution**

`Chop[]` is used because `WeierstrassP[]` sometimes returns small imaginary parts, due to rounding error, which confuse `ParametricPlot[]`.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{y0 = ν x0/6 - 1/12, yp0 = ν v0/6},
  With[{g3 = 4 y0^3 - 1/12 y0 - yp0^2},
   With[{t0 = InverseWeierstrassP[y0, {1/12 , g3}]},
    Column[{
      Show[
       StreamPlot[vf[ν], {x, -3, 6}, {u, -3, 3}, 
        StreamStyle -> {Red, Opacity[0.5]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
        PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.01]],
       ParametricPlot[
        {6/ν Chop@WeierstrassP[t + t0, {1/12 , g3}] + 1/(2 ν),
          6/ν Chop@WeierstrassPPrime[t + t0, {1/12 , g3}]},
        {t, -10, 10}],
       Graphics[{{PointSize[Large], Darker@Green,
          Point[{6/ν Re@WeierstrassP[t0, {1/12 , g3}] + 1/(2 ν), 
            6/ν Re@WeierstrassPPrime[t0, {1/12 , g3}]}]}}],
       GridLines -> {{x0}, {v0}}, ImageSize -> 400,
       FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, {v0}}, {Automatic, {x0}}},
       FrameLabel -> {x, v}
       ]
      }]
    ]]],
 {{ν, 0.408}, 0.2, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{x0, 0}, -2, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{v0, Sqrt[2]}, -1 + $MachineEpsilon, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: This is super insightful!  I would love to see your code for how you got this to plot.  So what you're saying is that as `\[Nu]` approaches this critical value, the unstable saddle is reached, and the position blows up because it repelled by this repulsive force?

Comment: Wow, this is crazy!  It's going to take me a while to read through it.  Thanks so much.  I've marked yours as the answer, and will come back to let you know if I have any questions

Comment: Read through this.  Very educational and informative.  No questions from me.  Great answer!!

Comment: @Danny Thanks! and you're welcome! :)

Comment: I hope this post shows people that solving certain nonlinear DEs with elliptic functions should not have to be too hard to do. A nice demo.

Answer (score 9):

This is common behavior for a nonlinear ODE near its separatrix.  Suppose that at large `t`, `x''[t]` vanishes.  Then the ODE becomes

```
k x[t] - ν knl x[t]^2 == 0
```

with solution

```
Solve[%, x[t]][[2]]
(* {x[t] -> k/(knl ν)} *)
```

It is straightforward to show by linearizing the ODE about `k/(knl ν)` that whenever `x[t]` exceeds this value, it grows exponentially, whereas when it is less than this value it oscillates indefinitely.  Below are results for `ν -> 0.408248294` (blue)

```
s = NDSolve[{m x''[t] + k x[t] - ν knl x[t]^2 == 0, x[0] == 0, 
     x'[0] == v0} /. {ν -> 0.408248294, knl -> 1, k -> 1, m -> 1, 
     v0 -> Sqrt[2]}, x[t], {t, 0, 100}, MaxSteps -> ∞] // First;
p1 = Plot[x[t] /. s, Join[{t}, Flatten[(x[t] /. s) /. t -> "Domain"]]];
```

and similarly for `ν -> 0.408248295` (orange).

```
Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> {-1.2, 4}]
```

[image]

This is not to say that oscillatory solutions do not exist for `ν` larger than the threshold determined here, but only that they do not exist for `v0 -> Sqrt[2]`.  Smaller values of `v0` allow oscillations at larger values of `v`.

**Addendum**

To illustrate how the separatrix can be computed over a reasonable distance, a question raised in a comment below,

```
s = NDSolve[{m x''[t] + k x[t] - ν knl x[t]^2 == 0, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == v0} /.
    {ν -> 1/Sqrt[6], knl -> 1, k -> 1, m -> 1, v0 -> Sqrt[2]}, x[t], {t, 0, 100}, 
    MaxSteps -> ∞, WorkingPrecision -> 90, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"] // First;
Plot[x[t] /. s, Join[{t}, Flatten[(x[t] /. s) /. t -> "Domain"]], PlotRange -> {0, 4}]
```

[image]

(My thanks to [MichaelE2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) for identifying `1/Sqrt[6]` as the separatrix value.}

Comment: Very insightful!  I understood that this behavior was dependent on the initial condition, but wasn't really sure about how to figure out the relationship.  I'm going to try your code out for myself and make sure that it makes sense to me.

Comment: Why would I expect x''[t] to disappear for large t?

Comment: @Dante  If you were to choose v precisely right and integrate the ODE with infinite precision, that is what you would get. This is the definition of the separatrix in most cases.  The addendum to my answer illustrates.

Comment: @Danny  Nicely done.  The existence of an invariant allows the order of the ODE to be reduced by one, so that the phase diagram can be plotted in a straightforward manner.  `Derivative[1][x][t] == 0` then gives the critical value of `ν`.

Comment: Ah, I accidentally deleted my comment instead of editing it.  Thanks for the additional insight!  You and @Michael E2 have been extremely helpful :)