# Plot inside Streamplot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I am looking to include plots in the $x,y$ plane that represent the lines that the fixed points of a dynamical system follow as the variable $l$ is varied. In doing this, I am trying to represent simultaneously, a plot of the phase space with the streamlines. Effectively, in the end, I want to have a scroller where I can vary $l$ and as $l$ is varied, the fixed point on the static lines will follow some dot. Currently, I have got the streamplot which varies as $l$ varies, all I need to do now is somehow include the functions that the fixed points trace out. I just don't know how to do it. This is my current code for the streamplot;

```
FPStream = 
 Manipulate[
  StreamPlot[
   LVA[2, 1, 1.2, 2.1, 0.6, l], {x, -0.4, 0.4}, {y, -0.4, 0.4}, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"l = ", l}], GridLines -> Automatic], {l, 0, 2}] 

How can I implement these plots?
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, MATHBOI! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Could you add the definition of `LVA` to your question?  Do you have an analytical expression for the equilibrium?

Comment: In each of the two `Manipulate` codes [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125470/4999), I think I do something like what you want.  Anyway, it might give you an idea.

Comment: Also, searching for [StreamPlot Maniplate Graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Streamplot+manipulate+Graphics) or  [StreamPlot Maniplate Epilog](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Streamplot+manipulate+Epilog) yield a few Q&A that combine `StreamPlot` with other plots and graphics.